# Reconnect to an existing database

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, qnap

I had to restore to a new HDD on my QNAP NAS. Everything is working OK again, except for phpMyAdmin and Wordpress.
I hoped that I simply could copy back my mysql and wordpress directories from my backup, but my databases do not appear in phpMyAdmin.
Obviously I am overlooking something :)
Are there any settings etc.. that I should look at? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it working again :)
I removed everything under .@mysql and stopped and then restarted the SQL server. I created a new mysql database with the same name as my old one. Then I copied the files from my old database (on my backup) to the new database. I also changed the root password in wp-config.php and then everything was working.
I am still trying to understand everything about mysql and wordpress, and maybe there was an easier way to solve this but I'm glad my websites are back :)